# How to bring up containers specified in docker-compose before starting xUnit tests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, .net-core

I need to run series of xUnit tests that depend on several Docker containers. I would prefer that xUnit takes care of the whole process - starting containers (similar to `docker-compose env up`), running tests and then tearing containers (i.e. `docker-compose env down`).

Is there support in Visual Studio or xUnit for this or this process needs to be manually implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this without any extra dependencies, you can use `Process.Start` that emulates starting through command line. Here is class that wraps and provides this functionality:

```
public class DockerStarter : IDisposable
{
    private const string DOCKER_COMPOSE = @"c:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-compose.exe";
    public string ComposeFile { get; set; }
    public string WorkingDir { get; set; }

    public DockerStarter(string composeFile, string workingDir)
    {
        ComposeFile = composeFile;
        WorkingDir = workingDir;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var startInfo = generateInfo("up");
        _dockerProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
        // TODO: Find better way to wait for Docker containers to start
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    private Process _dockerProcess;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _dockerProcess.Close();

        var stopInfo = generateInfo("down");
        var stop = Process.Start(stopInfo);
        stop.WaitForExit();
    }

    private ProcessStartInfo generateInfo(string argument)
    {
        var procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = DOCKER_COMPOSE,
            Arguments = $"-f {ComposeFile} {argument}",
            WorkingDirectory = WorkingDir
        };
        return procInfo;
    }
}
```

Obviously there are downsides to this approach:

- Fixed path to `docker-compose` executable
- Manual wait on container start

I'll see if there is better way to directly interact with Docker daemon and update answer if possible.